# Acceptance tests aren't resetting

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit

I have some acceptance tests that test a component. If I run each test separately, they pass just fine. However, when I run the tests together, they fail because they're retaining the values from the previous tests.

Here is my code:

**filter-test.js**

```
module('Integration - Filter', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    App = startApp();
    server = setupPretender();
    authenticateSession();
  },
  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
    server.shutdown();
  }
});

test('filters can be saved and selected via the dropdown', function(assert) {
  visit('/status');
  fillIn('.filter-status', 'Not Completed');
  fillIn('.filter-id', '444');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.ok(find('.status-title').text().includes('2 of 7'), 'the new filter filters the results');
  });
});

test('only saved filters can be edited', function(assert) {
  visit('/status');
  fillIn('.filter-id', 'not an id');
  click('.update-filter');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(find('.alert').text(), 'Not a Saved Filter×');
  });
});

test('filter values can be cleared', function(assert) {
  visit('/status');
  fillIn('.filter-id', '444');
  fillIn('.filter-status', 'Completed');
  click('.clear-filters');

  andThen(function() {
    // this fails because `.filter-id` is set to 'not an id':
    assert.equal(find('.filter-id').val(), '', 'filter for was reset to its initial value');
    // this also fails because `.filter-status` is set to 'Not Completed':
    assert.equal(find('.filter-status').val(), 'Everything', 'status dropdown was reset to its initial value');
  });
});
```

**ps-filter/component.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['panel', 'panel-default', 'filter-panel'],
  currentFilter: null,
  initialValues: null,

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.set('initialValues', Ember.copy(this.get('filterValues')));
  },

  actions: {
    saveFilter: function(name) {
      var filters = this._getFilterList();
      var filterValues = this.get('filterValues');

      if (!Ember.isEmpty(name)) {
        filters[name] = filterValues;

        this.sendAction('updateFilter', filters);
        this.set('currentFilter', name);
      }
    },

    updateFilter: function() {
      var filterValues = this.get('filterValues');
      var currentFilter = this.get('currentFilter')
      var filters = this.get('userFilters');

      filters[currentFilter] = filterValues;

      this.sendAction('updateFilter', filters);
    },

    clearFilters: function() {
      this.set('currentFilter', null);
      this.set('filterValues', Ember.copy(this.get('initialValues')));
    }
  }
});
```

**status/controller.js**

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  filterValues: {
    filterStatus: 'Everything',
    filterId: 'id',
  },
  userFilters: Ember.computed.alias('currentUser.content.preferences.filters')
});
```

**status/template.hbs**

```
<div class="row">
  {{ps-filter
    filterValues=filterValues
    userFilters=userFilters
    updateFilter='updateFilter'
  }}
</div>
```

From what I gathered, it seems that it sets the `initialValues` to the `filterValues` left over from the previous test. However, I thought that the `afterEach` was supposed to reset it to its original state. Is there a reason why it doesn't reset it to the values in the controller?

Note that the component works normally when I run it in development.

Ember versions listed in the Ember Inspector:

```
Ember      : 1.11.3
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.18
```

I'm running Ember CLI `0.2.7`.

**Edit**

I don't think this is the issue at all, but here is my pretender setup:

**tests/helpers/setup-pretender.js**

```
export default function setupPretender(attrs) {
  var users = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'ttest',
      preferences: null
    }
  ];

  var activities = [
    {
      id: 36874,
      activity_identifier: '18291',
      status: 'Complete'
    }, {
      id: 36873,
      activity_identifier: '82012',
      status: 'In Progress'
    }, {
      id: 35847,
      activity_identifier: '189190',
      status: 'In Progress'
    }, {
      id: 35858,
      activity_identifier: '189076',
      status: 'Not Started'
    }, {
      id: 382901,
      activity_identifier: '182730',
      status: 'Not Started'
    }, {
      id: 400293,
      activity_identifier: '88392',
      status: 'Complete'
    }, {
      id: 400402,
      activity_identifier: '88547',
      status: 'Complete'
    }
  ];

  return new Pretender(function() {
    this.get('api/v1/users/:id', function(request) {
      var user = users.find(function(user) {
        if (user.id === parseInt(request.params.id, 10)) {
          return user;
        }
      });

      return [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, JSON.stringify({user: user})];
    });

    this.get('api/v1/activities', function(request) {
      return [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, JSON.stringify({
        activities: activities
      })];
    });

    this.put('api/v1/users/:id', function(request) {
      var response = Ember.$.parseJSON(request.requestBody);
      response.user.id = parseInt(request.params.id, 10);

      var oldUser = users.find(function(user) {
        if (user.id === parseInt(request.params.id, 10)) {
          return user;
        }
      });
      var oldUserIndex = users.indexOf(oldUser);

      if (oldUserIndex > -1) {
        users.splice(oldUserIndex, 1);
        users.push(response.user);
      }

      return [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, JSON.stringify(response)];
    });
  });
}
```

When I run the tests, it fails because it reset the value to the one in the previous test. For example, when I run `'filter values can be cleared'`, the `.filter-id` input has the same `.filter-id` value from `'only saved filter can be edited`. If I change the value in `'only saved filters can be edited'`back to `''`, the `'filter values can be cleared'` test passes.

Basically, the component sets the `initialValues` property when it first inserts the element. It's set to a copy of the `filterValues` property, so it should be set to the controller's `filterValues` property, and shouldn't change. However, it seems that the modified `filterValues` property is carried over to the next test, which means that `initialValues` is set to that modified property when it rerenders. So, the test rerenders the templates, but retains the modified values in the controller and component.

I can make the tests pass by creating an `initialValues` property in the controller and passing that into the component, but that'd mean having duplicate properties in the controller (since `filterValues` and `initialValues` would have the same values).

I could modify the user record in the component, but I thought we're supposed to only modify records in the controller or router. Besides, isn't the `afterEach` hook supposed to reset the app?

Comment: just to clarify -is this a pretender problem? if so -can you show a lot more about your pretender setup/config/version ?

Comment: Sure, I'll include it. I don't think that's the case, since it looks like the component is retaining the `filterValues` from the previous tests. I'm willing to explore all possible solutions, though.